# Suppressing stderr in GNU Parallel

Tags: ubuntu, stderr, gnu-parallel

I'm using GNU Parallel to concurrently run a command several thousand times.

To get logs of the execution I'm using `--files` and `--results`.

To get nice progress bar while it's running I'm using `--eta` and `--progress`.

Now, my problem is that while STDERR is redirected to the files, it is still printed to the terminal, which corrupts my progress bar.

How can I suppress printing STDERR to terminal? I still want to have this information in the log files, so I can't just wrap the command into `2>/dev/null`.

So far my command line looks like this:

```
cat input.txt | parallel -P 10 --progress --eta --files --results output_dir/ "./script.sh some-arg {}"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a nice bar, may I suggest `--bar` instead of `--eta`? You need version 20131122 or later.

This seems to work, since STDERR files are not printed, so you get nothing on STDERR apart from the `--bar`:

```
cat input.txt | parallel -P 10 --bar --files --results output_dir/ "./script.sh some-arg {}" >/dev/null
```

Comment: I'm using parallel 20151122 with the `--bar` option and it does not suppress standard error.

Comment: Are you using --files?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
parallel --bar --jobs 10 '(ffmpegthumbnailer -i "{}" -o "/tmp/${DIR}/{}.jpg" -f 2>/dev/null)'  ::: *.mp4
```